# Android - stop move to main activity when rotating the device/emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

There is an application to load UI dynamically for a unique LinearLayout when button press.
The main UI is extends by Activity and others are extends by LinearLayout.The unique LinearLayout is in main UI.
Dynamically loading part is working smoothly.But when changing orientation of device or emulator it goes to main ui.I have a layout Stack to get current Layout(UI) at any given time.
I want to stop move to main UI when rotating the device/emulator.
Is it possible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because the activity is getting recreated on orientation change.
In your manifest file against the main activity add the following properties

```
 <activity android:name=".YourMainActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>
```

Comment: if its working, mark it answered so that other users can find the solution easily. Its a tick mark on the left hand side of the answer.

Comment: But there is an issue.Keyboard is not popup..I want it. any help?

Comment: it should popup if the focus is on an edittext. There is no reason why the keyboard would not show up. "keyboardHidden" over here does not mean 'hide the keyboard'

Comment: acording to the "keyboardHidden" - The keyboard accessibility has changed — for example, the user has revealed the hardware keyboard.That menas user uses the hardware keyboard..is it?But in portrait view works correctly.in landscape mode keyboard does not show soft keyboard..any idea?

Comment: That's fine Umesh..Soft keyboard does not showing in emulator but working in device. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believew this happens because you don't correctly handle the event of the orientation change. You should override `public void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig)`[method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) to handle this.

If you don't override it and don't force your actiivty to keep the orientation, when the orientation changes, the system will destroy your app and re-launch it. That's why you see the main UI again.

Solutions:

1. explicitly declare the orientation you want in the AndroidManifest.xml file, so such event will be ignored. something like: `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestActivity_screenOrientation) for more choice.
2. override the `onConfigurationChanged` method and chage your UI as you want inside that method, or simply do nothing so that this event would be ignored.